# How to convert timeMillis through minutes? And how to convert timeMillis through julianday?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I need to switch from timeMillis to minutes but that minutes  are in minutes since midnight. For example 1496358000000 should be 360.

And secondly, I need to switch from timeMillis to julian day. For example: long milis = 1496358000000 transferred to julian day is 2457907.
Can anyone help me how to convert it. Thank you!

edit: I did it! This is my method for converting to julianday

```
 public  int convertToCurentJulian(Calendar calendar){

    int year = calendar.get(calendar.YEAR);

    int month = calendar.get(calendar.MONTH)+1;
    int day = calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    int a = (14 - month) / 12;
    int y = year + 4800 - a;
    int m = month + 12 * a - 3;
    int jdn = day + (153 * m + 2)/5 + 365*y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 - 32045;

    return jdn;
}
```

- This is switch from timeInMillis to minutes:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

 cal.setTimeInMillis(longTimeMillis);

 int  minutesSinceMidnight=  (cal.get(cal.HOUR_OF_DAY)  * 60) +( cal.get(cal.MINUTE));
```

Comment: You need to decide, midnight in which time zone.

Comment: because I have already inserted  timeInMillis,  not need have time zone

Comment: On my computer your code yields 60 minutes, not 360. On a computer with `TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")`, it yields Julian day 2457906 (not 2457907) and 1140 minutes. Time zone makes a difference. If you’re happy with your code, so am I, just don’t expect it to yield the same result on all Android telephones.

Answer (score 1):

```
long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis);
```

Comment: I have tried but the output is some Incorrect as in my mail was placed above.

Comment: What was the output?

Comment: I have upvoted because for converting some number of milliseconds to equivalent number of minutes, this is the elegant and clear way of doing. For converting from milliseconds since the epoch to minutes since midnight in your own time zone, some other way is needed (I believe the asker intended the latter, but that was not clear).